# Cannot refer to a non-final variable inside an inner class defined in a different method- Please help me i am new at this

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Please, help me. I am trying to build a simple application in which you select a hobby from a spinner you click in the button "aceptar" and its return the string from that spinner to the main activity. I am getting the error "cannot refer to a non-final variable inside an inner class defined in a different method" in the variable "myspinner".

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;

    public class ActivitySaludo extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_saludo);
        String myspinner;

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String saludo = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_SALUDO);

        TextView txtCambiado = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TxtSaludo);
        txtCambiado.setText(getString(R.string.hola_saludo) + " " + saludo);

        final Spinner spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.SpinnerSaludo);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.hobby, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener () {


            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int pos, long id) {
                parent.getItemAtPosition(pos);
                myspinner = spinner.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                //another call

            }

        });

        final Button BtnAceptar=(Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonAceptar);
        BtnAceptar.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener (){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent iboton = new Intent();   


            }

        });

    }

}
```

Comment: Put a comment on line where you are getting the error.

Comment: In Android Studio you should have this auto-fixed.

Answer (score 3):

```
String myspinner
```

needs to be final, you cannot access a non final local variable inside an interface

so all you need to do is move `String myspinner` out of `onCreate` and make it a class wide variable. then you dont need it to be final

Answer (score 1):

That's because the spinner is declared outside the listener. You can either declare the spinner as final or declare it inside the listener.